# Symfony2, FOSUserBundle: trouble setting to only registered users are allowed access to all pages

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

I thought I did the settings correctly when I tried going on to the homepage (/) and it redirects me to the login page (/login). However, when I click on navigation menu such as about (/about) and inventory (/inventory), the pages were shown even when I am not logged on. Currently only the homepage is redirecting to login, but I need all pages to redirect to login if users are not signed on.

Here is my security.yml:

```
security:
encoders:
    FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: sha512

role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN

providers:
    fos_userbundle:
        id: fos_user.user_provider.username

firewalls:
    main:
        pattern: ^/
        form_login:
            provider: fos_userbundle
            csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
            default_target_path: /
        logout:       true
        anonymous:    true

access_control:
    - { path: ^/$, role: ROLE_USER }
    - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/admin/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

config.yml:

```
fos_user:
  db_driver: orm # other valid values are 'mongodb', 'couchdb' and 'propel'
  firewall_name: main
  user_class: Main\UserBundle\Entity\User
```

Am I missing someting?

EDIT: I guess the solution was to get rid of the "$" in the access control.

```
access_control:
    - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/admin/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
    - { path: ^/, roles: ROLE_USER }
```

Except with this after login it will redirect to a blank page that has a URL of /_wdt/(token number). If anyone is having problem with this the solution is to insert this setting before the "main" in the security.yml's firewall:

```
dev:
   pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
   security: false
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your firewall configuration to the following:

```
access_control:
    - { path: ^/$, role: ROLE_USER }
    - { path: ^/secured, role: ROLE_USER }
    - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/admin/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

And change your routes for the secured pages to start with `/secured`.

**UPDATE:**

You can deny all the routes after / if user is not logged on by removing $ in your access control rule:

```
access_control:
    - { path: ^/, role: ROLE_USER }
```

However, this will cause a redirect loop when you try to access routes that should be available to anonymous users, like `/login` or `/register`.

**UPDATE 2**

As @user3757305 commented below, `- { path: ^/, role: ROLE_USER }` can be added at the bottom. Access control rules are applied in the order they appear in the security config. That means that everything above the `- { path: ^/, role: ROLE_USER }` rule will not be covered by it. So, the following config should work as required:

```
access_control:
    - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/admin/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
    - { path: ^/, role: ROLE_USER }
```

Comment: there's no way to just deny all the routes after / if user is not logged on?

Comment: I think if you put `- { path: ^/, role: ROLE_USER }` at the very bottom, it's sparing the anonymous access routes. It's working for me.

Comment: Probably correct, because access control rules are processed in the order they appear in security config. I will update my answer.